# Table doesn't exist within FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I'm currently developing an administration interface with FOSUserBundle, but I'm facing an annoying issue:

I've created an Operator class to hold FOSUserBundle's users, which is mapped in Symfony2 using Doctrine ORM. The first letter of Operator is uppercase (the rest of the tables in the website are also prefixed with capital letters, so I didn't want to break that convention).

The issue is that when I log in my administration interface, an error pops saying:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.operator' doesn't exist
```

Obviously, the query should use `dbname.Operator`, not `dbname.operator`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: attached the class definition of the `Operator` Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Operator")
 */
class Operator extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

}
```

Comment: check if annotation define in class for table is in lowercase.

Comment: Which OS do you run your app on? If you're on `*nix` you should be aware of case-sensitive policy... => `Operator != operator`

Comment: If there is any chance u generated mapping in yml file and later changed to annotations??

Comment: @jperovic That's precisely the point... FOSUserBundle seems to creates its query using a lowercase `o`, even though I specified `Operator` with a capital letter in the annotation.

Comment: @basantrijal Nope, I've always used annotations from the beginning.

Comment: Try deleting entity update your schema and create entity again and update schema.

Comment: Delete/update/re-add/update didn't help, unfortunately. I think I'll try to recreate my entity using a lowercase first letter, for the time being. I let this question open, hopefully someone will have a bright idea on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have you run

```
doctrine:schema:update --force
```

To create the database table?

Comment: Yes, I did that even twice. It does not report any error on the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the database table name in your entity.

If you use annotations, your entity should start something like this:

```
/**
 * Operator 
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Operator")
 */
class Operator
{
```

Comment: Actually annotations are already set. For reference, I've added the entity definition is my original post.